# JPA ManyToMany -relationship - joinTable not populated

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

My Join-Table will be not populated,
Here are my classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "RECIPIENT")
public class Recipient implements Serializable {

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Email.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "EMAIL_RECIPIENT", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "RECIPIENT_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "EMAIL_ID", nullable = false)})
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
 private Set<Email> emails;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "EMAIL")
public class Email implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "EMAIL_ID")
    private Integer emailId;

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Recipient.class, mappedBy = "emails")
    private Set<Recipient> recipients;

}
```

In my services-class I save the data the following way:

```
public void saveEmail(EmailDTO emailDTO) {
    //Save to the db
    final Email myEmail = new Email();
    myEmail .copyFrom(emailDTO);
    for (Recipient recipient : myEmail.getRecipients()) {
        recipient.getEmails().add(myEmail );
        recipientRepository.save(recipient);
    }
    recipientRepository.flush();
    emailRepository.save(myEmail );
    emailRepository.flush();
}
```

Now my join-table looks like this:

```
 Email-ID       Recipient_ID
 67891          test@domain.com
```

It only does an update..the join table should look like this:

```
 Email-ID       Recipient_ID
 12343          test@domain.com
 54678          test@domain.com
 67891          test@domain.com
```

EDIT

I was wrong it doesn't do an update..I saw in the log files that it deletes the inserted row from.before for example if in a  join-table there would be a row like this:

```
Email-ID    : 1234  , 
Recipient_ID:test@domain.com
```

then it just deletes this row and adds the new email id like:

```
Email-ID    : 5678  Recipient_ID:test@domain.com
```

This is in the logs, first it deletes:

```
delete from email_recipient where recipient_id=? and email_id=?
```

Then it inserts:

```
insert into email_recipient (recipient_id, email_id) values (?, ?)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bidirectional relation which means each side of the relation should have a reference to the other side, so in addition to your email having a list of recipents, each recipent need to have a list of emails, so I would suggest to initialize the list of emails inside recipent, your Recipient class should look like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "RECIPIENT")
public class Recipient implements Serializable {

@ManyToMany(targetEntity = Email.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "EMAIL_RECIPIENT", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "RECIPIENT_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "EMAIL_ID", nullable = false)})
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
 private List<Email> emails = new ArrayList<>()
...getter setters
}
```

now when iterating over the Recipent add email to the list of emails for each recipent

```
 List<Recipient> recipientList = new ArrayList<Recipient>(email.getRecipients());
email.setRecipients(new ArrayList<Recipient>());
 for (Recipient recipient : recipientList) {
        recipient.getEmails().add(email);
          email.getRecipients().add(email);
         Recipient persistedRecipient = recipientRepository.save(recipient);

         email = persistedRecipient.getEmails().get(persistedRecipient.getEmails().size()-1);//get the managed email
    }
```

Another approach would be doing the same (adding the email to recipient) and change the cascade to be in the email and saving the email.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "RECIPIENT")
public class Recipient implements Serializable {

@ManyToMany(targetEntity = Email.class)
@JoinTable(name = "EMAIL_RECIPIENT", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "RECIPIENT_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "EMAIL_ID", nullable = false)})
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
private Set<Email> emails = new HashSet<>();

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "EMAIL")
public class Email implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "EMAIL_ID")
private Integer emailId;

@ManyToMany(targetEntity = Recipient.class, mappedBy = "emails"وcascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Recipient> recipients = new HashSet<>();

}
```

And in your saveEmail method

```
public void saveEmail(EmailDTO emailDTO) {
//Save to the db
final Email myEmail = new Email();
myEmail .copyFrom(emailDTO);
for (Recipient recipient : myEmail.getRecipients()) {
    recipient.getEmails().add(myEmail );

}

emailRepository.save(myEmail );
```

}

Comment: I did that (editet my question), however I get the same result

Comment: @Norbert94 please recheck the anser , you missed getting the managed email in the loop

Comment: I am using a HashSet, therefore I cannot get the email (I've updated my question)

Comment: @Norbert94 is there a specific reason for using HashSet in your case?

Comment: No, I just followed the tutorials, which mostly use HashSet? Do you think this problem is connected with my problem, that the join table is not populated correctly, or is this an additional problem in my code? Do I need to use a List?

Comment: try to use the list so you can retrieve the email as i mentioned

Comment: I am using a List now, I get an ORA-00001: Unique Constraint (EMAIL_RECIPIENT_PK) error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152703/discussion-between-amer-qarabsa-and-norbert94).

Comment: Howe would the code look like if the email is the owner. The model of email and recipient is clear but how would I populate the data?

Comment: @Norbert94 check the answer